# EVITAR BORRADO FORMULARIO Y DESHABILITAR INPUT UNA VEZ ENVIADO

Tags: javascript, html5

Tengo un formulario donde introduzco el nombre y número de jugadas y se valida. Una vez hecho esto se envía el formulario para empezar el juego.

Necesito que al enviar el formulario se mantenga el nombre y el número de jugadas y además que se deshabilite el campo del formulario para que no se puedan introducir nuevos datos.

Esta es mi función:

```
function validar(evento) {
  evento.preventDefault();
  const nombre = document.getElementById("nombreJugador");
  const partidas = document.getElementById("numPartidas");
  const expresion1 = /[A-Za-z]{3,}/;

  if (!expresion1.test(nombre.value)) {
    nombre.classList.add("fondoRojo");
    return false;
  }

  if (partidas.value <= 0) {
    partidas.classList.add("fondoRojo");
    return false;
  }
  this.submit();
```

Y este mi botón:

```
<button type="submit">¡JUGAR!</button>
```

El formulario se envía pero no consigo que se mantengan los datos y se deshabilite el campo.

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Si lo haces por ajax podras controlar ese comportamiento. Mira que ahora mismo estas haciendo un submit() normal dentro del javascript, lo que implica refrescar la página.  Otro modo: Ya que haces un submit, y el formulario se recarga, puedes controlar tambien ese aspecto en el PHP que lo procesa (si es PHP) y al generar el formulario tener en cuenta si ha habido un POST de esos datos antes o no, para preasignarlos durante la creación del formulario.  Sin más código donde se vea como procesas el formulario en el PHP y su HTML poco más te puedo ayudar.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo por AJAX y mi formulario es este:

Comment: No intentes agregar código en un comentario. Pulsa sobre el enlace [edit] que aparece en el pie de la pregunta para agregar/modificar lo que necesites de tu pregunta.  Diria que no lo estás haciendo por AJAX, porque el `this.submit()` no es ajax.

Comment: el formulario no deberia limpiar sus campos si no colocals un reset y para que no se pueda modificar lo entrado abajo del preventDefault() colocas document.getElementById("tuCampo").disabled = true;